# Express error handling - app crashes when error is thrown instead of going into the error handler

Tags: node.js

I have a problem with my node app. I set up an error handling middleware and when I throw an error in the controller, the app crashes instead of going into the error handler.

ErrorHandler.js

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

exports.ErrorHandler = (err, req, res, next) => {
  console.log(err);

  if (err instanceof mongoose.Error.ValidationError) {
    return res.status(422).json(err.errors);
  }

  if (err instanceof mongoose.Error.CastError) {
    return res.status(404).json({ message: "Resource not found" });
  }

  return res.status(500).json(err);
};
```

AuthController.js

```
  static init = async (req, res) => {
    throw new NotFoundError("Not found");
}
```

Comment: How are you calling the ErrorHandler ? We can't help you if you doesn't show how are you calling it. It seems that your problem is related to how are you calling this middleware.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't know how you're calling the ErrorHandler and if you're using express, but I think you're using it. Although I think I can give to you a simple example of usage of ErrorHandler as middleware:

```
function errorHandler(error, req, res, next) {
  res.status(error.status || 500);
  res.send({
    error: {
      message: error.message,
    },
  });
}

// Error-handling middleware 
app.use(errorHandler);

//example
app.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
  next(new Error('Error for understanding the ErrorHandler'));
});
```

In this example your app won't crashes.

Please read this official guide to complete understand how it works: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html

Comment: Your answer is correct for *server errors* (e.g. HTTP 500).  The OP might be conflating HTTP *PROTOCOL ERRORS* (e.g. HTTP 500) with NodeJS *EXCEPTIONS* (e.g. "throw SomeException").  For the latter, the OP would need a try/catch block, per ifmatic's reply: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75892509/421195

Answer (score 2):

You have to use try and catch in your controller. Then call next in the catch function as follows:

```
static init = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    throw new NotFoundError("Not found");
  } catch(error) {
    next(error)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try to install and import this package
https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-async-errors

It might be the error is thrown in async function and `next()` is not called as mentioned in express docs.

`express-async-errors` handles this for us.